# Using a kickstart file with liveinst

Tags: centos7, kickstart, anaconda

I have a kickstart file that I generated while doing a manual, graphical install. I'm trying to use this kickstart file while booted to CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1810.iso and running 
`/usr/bin/liveinst -C --kickstart=/root/mykickstart.ks` 
but I'm having no success with getting Anaconda (liveinst) to recognize my instructions regarding partitioning of the disk.
Has any of you ever got this to work? Is kickstart the right path? What about these https://anaconda-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot-options.html#  commands?

I'm tasked with 'upgrading' CentOS 6.x to CentOS 7.6 on a machine that has no connection to any CentOS repo, so this would involve overwriting the root logical volume and boot partition. I need to leave the home logical volume untouched. 
Ideally my user would click the "Install to disk" launcher on the desktop and not have to answer any installer questions but for now I'd just like to figure out how to communicate effectively with Anaconda.

Again when I say "upgrade" I really mean "fresh install" while leaving /home intact.

thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Live media do not allow a normal installation. It can just clone the live image to disk and make it bootable.

If you want a custom install and/or use kickstart you will need the normal anaconda installer. If you don't have networking, you'll need CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1810.iso.

Getting the kickstart file to the machine without network can be done. However, last time I did this I put the kickstart file onto a floppy which doesn't seem right in 2019.